# Компактное хранение String в файле

Tags: строки, delphi, файлы

Пишу на Delphi 11.3 программу. В которой много записей типа String, которые нужно хранить в файле. String[255] (ShortString) занят примерно 5-15 символов (хранятся слова на русском).
При записи в файл, очень много пустого места в записанных полях String[255].
Помню в 90х был формат StringZ, заканчивающийся 0 в конце строки. И читая файл по признаку [0] можно было определить маркер конца строки.
Теоретически я так и хочу переделать и читать побайтно, отслеживая 0 как маркер конца строки.Т.к. база данных слов, весит 2 гига (слово+0). И если в память загрузить ее в поля типа String[255] то это очень много памяти :)
Хранение в архиве не рассматривается, т.к. нужен быстрый (по хешу) доступ к словам, находящимся в памяти.

Но может быть с 90х что-то поменялось и появились новые алгоритмы, для хранения компактных записей? Есть предложения по компактному хранения в файле записей String?

Comment: А файл вы читаете-пишете постоянно или один раз прочитали, поработали, потом записали или как? Если целиком пишете-читаете, то не очень понимаю, почему бы не использовать упаковку при хранении в файле.

Comment: Файл сразу читается в память. И собственно не меняется, в нем ВСЕ слова русского языка :) А слова в файл собирает и добавляет другая программа. Т.к. появляются новые слова.

Comment: Может лучше вообще тогда БД завести? Хотя бы в виде `sqlite` я там не знаю. Чтобы проще было что-то добавлять в БД. И в БД обычно есть тип `nvarchar`, без лишних пустых позиций в конце.

Comment: В базе слов примерно 250.000. И хранить в памяти слово из 5-15 символов не рентабельно. Самое длинное слово 35 символов, я такое поле для всех слов и задал String[35]. Но это все равно жрет много памяти. Много не использованного пространства занято, более 50% по сути. 5-15 символов помещены в поле на 35.

Comment: SQLite на рассматривал т.к. мне кажется что там не компактно хранятся строки. Ведь там тоже задаешь полю размер.

Comment: А так то я про дельфи ничего не знаю, во всех современных языках строки храняться именно по актуальному числу символов, ничего лишнего. Что питон взять, что C#, например.

Comment: Ну StringZ я в 90х у Си и Си++ подсмотрел. Но в делфи нет такого типа данных. И в памяти и в файле 35 байт на одно слово. Плюс хэш Integer. 9.7 гига весит все это. И я еще хочу поля добавить :)

Comment: При SQLite все хранится на диске. И за каждым словом нужно давать запрос. Это долго :)

Comment: Ну ничего по идее не мешает в нетипизированный файл побайтно записать строку, потом нулевой байт. Хотя, с тем же успехом можно обычный текстовый файл для хранения использовать с переносами строк или пробелами в качестве разделителей.

Comment: Короче, просто используйте текстовый файл, оверхэд будет минимальный.

Comment: А поле Хэш куда деть? :) Хэш это сумма символов в строке, как ключ для быстрого доступа.

Comment: Хэш в какой момент используется? Если после загрузки, то вообще его можно не хранить в файле, а вычислять.

Comment: 250.000 хешей пересчитывать? :) Лучше их в параллельном файле хранить. Как первые БД были. БД файл и IDX файл с индексами :)

Comment: Задумка с хэшами такая, пользователь вводит слово и по сумме символов в нем получается хэш (ключ, индекс) и по нему находится слово. И в дальнейшем в файле хранятся хэши слов, для компактности хранения (4 байта на слово). Что позволяет в дальнейшем восстановить диалог :)

Comment: @FrancNet, да, именно пересчитывать. Это не будет сильно дольше, чем прочитать эти же хеши из файла (скорее всего примерно +- то же самое время). Если бы там были какие-то гигантские строки, и суперсложный алгоритм хэширования - еще ладно, можно было бы что-то тут пытаться оптимизировать.

Comment: Там еще дополнительная математика идет, т.к. слова "да" и "ад" имеют равный хеш. Там в ответе предложили варианты Ansi, TStringList пробую :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вы бы хоть книжку какую почитали...

Строки переменной длины были ещё в Турбо Паскале. Это просто `String` без указания длины. Тогда длина хранилась в нулевом байте, теперь в специальном месте перед телом строки.

В актуальных версиях Дельфи есть `AnsiString` и `String = UnicodeString` (если нет спецнастроек компилятора).

Текстовый файл можно прочитать в `TStringList` и работать уже со списком.

Дополнительные данные можно хранить в том же текстовом файле в формате ключ-значение. Если под это жалко места - то бинарный файл, из-за разной длины строк он будет последовательного доступа.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что в TStringList строки будут хранится в том кол-ве сколько занимают?
Просто сейчас у String нет ограничения в 255 символов!

Comment: TStringList хранит указатели на строки (4 или 8 байт). Сама строка занимает (Length+1)*SizeOf(Char)+8-12 байт на служебную информацию  https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Long_String_Types

Comment: Да я проверил, там метод есть SaveToFile. И действительно хранит без лишних мест. И там есть встроенный метод GetHashCode. Но не совсем устроено как мне хотелось. В общем спасибо, пробую :)

Comment: В TDictionary я не могу поменять значение ключа (индекса).
Надеюсь в TStringList нет ограничения в 2 гига? На многое такие ограничения стоят.

Comment: Есть ограничение на размер строк и на количество в списке. Индекс же Integer

Comment: Ну у меня 250.000 индексов +- А строки до 35 символов.

Comment: Ну это мелочи..

Comment: @FrancNet Если вам мешает ограничение на 2 гига, то нужно компилировать приложение как 64х-битное. Кроме того, если количество строк больше MAXINT (если я правильно помню), то придётся написать свой (или найти готовый) аналог TStringList, который может столько хранить.

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы приложение в конечном счете работало и на 32 бита. Ноутбуков еще куча с 2-3 гига оперативки ;)

Comment: Я не вижу, что этому бы мешало

Comment: Ну посоветовали в х64 компилить. Там 2 гига ограничения нет. Я думаю что все влезет и менее 2 гиг.

Comment: Ваши данные - всего лишь десятки мегабайт, до ограничений далековато